# Position of the legend in a Bokeh plot

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

Does anyone know how to carry the legend in bokeh **outside** of the graph? The only manipulation I could do was to choose a position among:

```
top_right, top_left, bottom_left or bottom_right
```

using:

```
legend()[0].orientation = "bottom_left"
```

and when I try different ones I get the error message:

```
ValueError: invalid value for orientation: 'outside'; allowed values are top_right, top_left, bottom_left or bottom_right
```

Comment: One more question closely relate to this: how to keep the aspect ratio of the original axes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.4` it is possible to position legends outside the central plot area.  Here is a short example [from the user's guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area):

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

output_file("legend_labels.html")

p = figure(toolbar_location="above")

r0 = p.circle(x, y)
r1 = p.line(x, y)

r2 = p.line(x, 2*y, line_dash=[4, 4], line_color="orange", line_width=2)

r3 = p.square(x, 3*y, fill_color=None, line_color="green")
r4 = p.line(x, 3*y, line_color="green")

legend = Legend(items=[
    ("sin(x)",   [r0, r1]),
    ("2*sin(x)", [r2]),
    ("3*sin(x)", [r3, r4])
], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

show(p)
```

To adjust the position, change `dx` and `dy` in `location=(dx, dy)`.

[image]

Comment: How would I do that when using the charts API?

Comment: It would require moving the layout location, which is not trivial to do at the moment. I'd suggest bringing that kind of question to the mailing list, because it might take some experimentation and back and forth discussion to figure out.

Comment: I had [filed an issue for that feature](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4941).

Comment: I prefer using `location=(10, -30)` so that there is a small amount of separation between the plot and the legend.

Comment: One more question closely relate to this: how to keep the aspect ratio of the original axes?

Comment: Aspect ratio control is a new feature coming in `0.12.7`

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area

Answer (score 5):

According to the Bokeh [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html) and bigreddot, one way is to use the **Legend** command. I found another way.

If you use the **legend_label** argument in the plotting functions such as quad() or line(), the plot labels are appended to the `p.legend`. The location of the legend is defined by `p.legend.location = "center"` as a normal way.

To put the legend **outside**, you should use `p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')`.

Here is the above code in a different way.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

output_file("legend_labels.html")

p = figure()

p.circle(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")
p.line(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")

p.line(x, 2*y, legend_label="2*sin(x)",
       line_dash=[4, 4], line_color="orange", line_width=2)

p.square(x, 3*y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", fill_color=None, line_color="green")
p.line(x, 3*y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", line_color="green")

p.legend.location = "center"

########################################################
# This line puts the legend outside of the plot area

p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')
########################################################

show(p)
```

Comment: As a heads up to other people that try this: this adds a duplicate legend to your figure. If you try to do other things with your legend later (as I did) this will cause you a ton of headaches. Just handcraft a Legend object as recommended in the top answer.