# How do I create a pie chart using Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

All I'd like to do is create a pie chart. The Bokeh documentation covers a number of sophisticated charts, including a donut chart, but it doesn't seem to cover pie chart.

Is there any example of this?

Ultimately, the chart will need to be to be embedded in a webpage, so I'll need to take advantage of Bokeh's html embed capabilities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer below is very outdated. The `Donut` function was part of the old `bokeh.charts` API that was deprecated and removed long ago. For any modern version of Bokeh (e.g. 0.13 or newer) you can create a pie chart using the wedge glyphs, as follows:

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

x = { 'United States': 157, 'United Kingdom': 93, 'Japan': 89, 'China': 63,
    'Germany': 44, 'India': 42, 'Italy': 40, 'Australia': 35,
    'Brazil': 32, 'France': 31, 'Taiwan': 31, 'Spain': 29 }

data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'country'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Pie Chart", toolbar_location=None,
        tools="hover", tooltips="@country: @value")

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='country', source=data)

show(p)
```

[image]

---

---

---

***OUTDATED BELOW***

An example for Bokeh 0.8.1 using the `bokeh.plotting` interface:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from numpy import pi

# define starts/ends for wedges from percentages of a circle
percents = [0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 1]
starts = [p*2*pi for p in percents[:-1]]
ends = [p*2*pi for p in percents[1:]]

# a color for each pie piece
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow"]

p = figure(x_range=(-1,1), y_range=(-1,1))

p.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=1, start_angle=starts, end_angle=ends, color=colors)

# display/save everythin  
output_file("pie.html")
show(p)
```

Bokeh >0.9 will correctly compute the bounding area of all glyphs, not just "pointlike" marker glyphs, and explicitly setting the ranges like this will not be required.

Comment: Great. And I can label them the same way I would label other glyphs, right?

Comment: There are several ways to label. You can add a legend (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/legend.py) or you can use the `text` method on the plot to add text labels yourself. The easiest way to set the axis labels is to pass, e.g, `x_axis_label` to the call to `figure`

Comment: For those like myself who suck at Pandas. This is how you can get the `percents` from a data series: `percents = [0]+list(ds.cumsum()/ds.sum())percents = [0]+list(ds.cumsum()/ds.sum())`. I don't know, if there is an easier way, but I added legends like this: `p = figure()` followed by `for start, end, legend,color in zip(starts, ends, list(ds.index), colors)` and then `p.wedge(color=color, legend=legend, ...)` as above. And finally here it is explained how to place the legend next to the pie chart (making it smaller unfortunately): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254619

Answer (score 9):

***NOTE from project maintainers: This answer refers to an old `bokeh.charts` API that was remove from bokeh a long time ago***

A `Donut` chart will return a simple pie chart if you input a pandas series rather than a dataframe. And it will display labels too!

```
from bokeh.charts import Donut, show
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series([0.15,0.4,0.7,1.0], index = list('abcd'))
pie_chart = Donut(data)
show(pie_chart)
```

[image: Donut Chart]

Comment: This is definitely an easier solution, but I would still recommend the answer by @bigreddot, because using wedges allows the creation of labels. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3843

Comment: In bokeh version 0.12.10, this throws error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.charts'`

Comment: in Bokeh 0.12.10 bokeh.charts have been migrated out of bokeh core. It is now supported by http://holoviews.org/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers above for helping me as well. I want to add how to add a legend to your pie-chart as I had some trouble with that. Below is just a snippet. My piechart just had 2 sections. Thus, I just made a pie chart figure and called wedge on it twice:

```
import numpy as np
percentAchieved  = .6
pieFigure = figure(x_range=(-1, 1), y_range=(-1, 1))
starts = [np.pi / 2, np.pi * 2 * percentAchieved + np.pi / 2]
ends = [np.pi / 2+ np.pi * 2 * percentAchieved, np.pi / 2 + 2*np.pi]
pieColors = ['blue', 'red']
#therefore, this first wedge will add a legend entry for the first color 'blue' and label it 'hello'
pieFigure.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=.7, start_angle=starts, end_angle=ends, color=pieColors, legend="hello")
#this will add a legend entry for the 'red' color and label it 'bye'. Made radius zero to not make 
#another piechart overlapping the original one
pieFigure.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=0, start_angle=starts, end_angle=ends, color=pieColors[1], legend="bye")
```