# bokeh multiple figures with shared legend

Tags: python, bokeh

When following the [bokeh docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/layout.html) for making gridplots, if I use `figure`'s `legend` keyword argument I get a legend inside each subplot. How could I get a shared legend for the entire gridplot? Further, how could I get a shared legend between say 3 out of 4 of the subplots?

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254619/position-of-the-legend-in-a-bokeh-plot is an example to answers your question.

Comment: @elsa I don't think that's what the OP meant... I'm in the same boat, I have 4 figures that I plot together using 1 layout and would like to share the Legend across them (they use the same labels and colors).

Comment: My solution for this is usually to add the legend to a single subplot, wherever it makes more sense in each scenario, then that legend works as the "shared" legend. I didn't know about using negative numbers with the "location" attribute, as mentioned in @elsa's link; that might work even better.

Answer (score 3):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0`, it is not possible to share legends between plots, nor to have legends contain renderers from outside the plot they are defined on. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7607) you can follow for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no official support.
Here is an advice that barely qualifies as an answer -

```
You can plot one extra empty figure in your grid with legends ON
which can act as a reference for your plots where legend is OFF.
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show how to use the empty plot legend in the other plots? Do you need to write a Javascript callback?